# JQuery expandable table options will not hide automatically

Tags: jquery, html-table, show-hide

I'm pretty new to JQuery and have pretty shoddy Javascript skills, so apologies if I've missed something really obvious.

I have use the following code from the source below to make a table that has items that expand with more information once clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle('fast');
        });
    $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('tr');
});
```

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/

Currently by default the table is showing the child information (that should be hidden), but will collapse when the row is clicked on.

I would like it to be hidden by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is producing the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@class^=child-]
```

What you need is:

```
$('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('tr');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZD4qE/

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch that before.
Though the error still seems to be there and is producing the same error in jquery even after the code change.

Comment: And it has not actually fixed the automatically hiding rows problem!
Could it be something to do with the way I have implemented it in my HTML?

Comment: Post your HTML then and we'll see. Try putting your code into my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD4qE/) if that helps too.

Comment: Ah brilliant it seems to be working (after re-trying it again today). Only obvious answer I can think of as to why this didn't work first time is that it could have been a cache refresh problem!